# Knockout checkbox selection filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, viewmodel

I am new at knockoutjc library, and can you help me? I have created a new model in javascript like this.

[image]

The code is here:

```
        <h2>Category : Throusers</h2>

    <h3>Sizes</h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: size.id" />
            <label data-bind="text: size.name"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Colors</h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: color.id" />
            <label data-bind="    text: color.name"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Products</h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
        <li>
            <label data-bind="text: name"></label> - 
            <label data-bind="text: size.name"></label>-
            <label data-bind="text: color.name"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Color(id, name) {
            return {
                id: ko.observable(id),
                name: ko.observable(name)
            };
        };

        function Size(id, name) {
            return {
                id: ko.observable(id),
                name: ko.observable(name)
            };
        }

        function Product(id,name, size, color) {
            return {
                id: ko.observable(),
                name: ko.observable(name),
                size: size,
                color: color
            };
        };

        var CategoryViewModel = {
            id: ko.observable(1),
            name: ko.observable("Throusers"),
            products: ko.observableArray([
                new Product(1,"Levi's 501", new Size(1, "30-32"), new Color(1, "Red")),
                new Product(2,"Colins 308", new Size(2, "32-34"), new Color(2, "Black")),
                new Product(3,"Levi's 507", new Size(1, "30-32"), new Color(3, "Blue"))
            ])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(CategoryViewModel);
    </script>
```

And now,

1. I wanna this: duplicated Sizes and colors should not list.
2. When I select a color from colors, selected color products should list and others should be disabled

If model is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an attempt to solve your problem.
I wrote everything from scratch, take a look. There might be a few bugs, didn't have time to test it a lot. But you can now add easily any custom filters you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/8y5PP/12/

```
    //    jQuery 1.10 loaded

var myAPP = (function($,ko){

    // trouserModel constructor
    var TrouserModel = function(id,name,color,size,visible){
        // maybe better if fields are ko observable, depends on other details
        this.id = id||0,
        this.name = name||'',
        this.color = color||'',
        this.size = size||'',
        this.visible = visible||true;

        return ko.observable(this);
    }

    // main viewmodel
    var trouserProducts = {
        data: ko.observableArray(),
        filters: ko.observableArray()
    }

    trouserProducts.sizeFilter = ko.computed(setFilter('size'));
    trouserProducts.colorFilter = ko.computed(setFilter('color'));
    trouserProducts.updateFilter = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        var ar = trouserProducts.data();
        if(!ar[0]) return true;
        var activeFilters = trouserProducts.filters().filter(function(el){return el().on;});

        for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++){

            for(var j=0; j<activeFilters.length; j++){
                var thisProp = ar[i]()[activeFilters[j]().prop].toLowerCase();

                if( thisProp===activeFilters[j]().value ){
                    var that = ar[i]();

                    ar[i]({
                        id: that.id,
                        name: that.name,
                        color: that.color,
                        size: that.size,
                        visible: true
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( j===activeFilters.length ){
                var that = ar[i]();

                ar[i]({
                    id: that.id,
                    name: that.name,
                    color: that.color,
                    size: that.size,
                    visible: false
                });
            }
        }

        return true;
    };

    // helper functions
    var makeFilter = function(prop,value){
        var ar = trouserProducts.filters()
            value = value.toLowerCase();    //    normalize values (OPTIONAL)

        for(var i=0; i < ar.length ;i++){
            var that = ar[i]();

            if(that.prop===prop && that.value===value){
                that.on = true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        // add filter
        trouserProducts.filters.push(ko.observable({ 
            prop: prop,
            value: value,
            on: true,
            updateFilter: function(){
                trouserProducts.updateFilter();
                return true;
            }
        }));
    }

    // return a function with a specific filter
    function setFilter(prop){
        var prop = prop,
            propFilter = function(el,i,ar){
                // el is ko observable filter here
                return el().prop === prop;
            };

        return function(){            
            return trouserProducts.filters().filter(propFilter);
        }
    };

    var addTrouser = function(id,name,color,size){
        var newTrouser = new TrouserModel(id,name,color,size);
        color && makeFilter('color',color);  // make color filter
        size && makeFilter('size',size);     // make size filter
        trouserProducts.data.push(newTrouser);  // add new trouserModel
    }

    return {
        trouserProducts: trouserProducts,
        addTrouser: addTrouser
    }
}(jQuery,ko));

// add your initial products here
myAPP.addTrouser(1,"Levi's 501","Red","30-32");
myAPP.addTrouser(2,"Levi's 507","Black","32-34");
myAPP.addTrouser(3,"Levi's 507","Black","30-32");
myAPP.addTrouser(4,"Dirty jeans","Blue","32-34");
myAPP.addTrouser(5,"Dirty jeans","Red","32-34");

ko.applyBindings(myAPP.trouserProducts);

window.myAPP = myAPP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your sizes and colors on your product model, you should store them separately -- like a normalized database.

Store only the id of the size and the color for what is available in the product model.

The foreach for the color list and the size list should then be iterating over all sizes in the size model and all colors in the color model.

Add a `visible` binding to the product list. Return true if the product has the size id and color id.

Lastly, I'd probably also make the size and color properties of your product model into arrays so that each product can have multiple colors and sizes associated with it.